# Why do map, every, and other array functions skip empty values?

Tags: javascript

## Background

I was writing some code to check if 2 arrays where the same but for some reason the result was true when expecting false. On closer inspection I found that where array values where undefined they were skipped.

## Example

```js
const arr1 = [, , 3, 4]
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const result = arr1.every((item, index) => item === arr2[index])
console.log(result) // true (HOW????)
```

## What I've tried

So I spent some time trying to get the value in here correctly but the only thing I've come up with is a regular for loop that makes iterations based on array length not the actual items.

## Question

Why does this happen and is there a way to recognise these empty/undefined values in my array?

Comment: *"callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values."* Right there in the documentation [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Description).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's an extension of the fact that `forEach` only visits elements that actually exist. I don't know that there's a deeper "why" for that other than that it didn't make much sense to call the callback for a missing element.

You can realize those elements (if that's the world) by using:

1. Spread notation, or
2. `Array.from`, or
3. `Array.prototype.values`, or
4. `Array.prototype.entries`

...or possibly some others.

```js
const a = [, , 3];
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty(0)); // false
const b = [...a];
console.log(b.hasOwnProperty(0)); // true
const c = Array.from(a);
console.log(b.hasOwnProperty(0)); // true
```

Applying that to your function with `Array.from`:

```js
const arr1 = [, , 3, 4]
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const result = Array.from(arr1).every((item, index) => item === arr2[index])
console.log(result) // false
```

Of course, that involves creating a new array and looping through the previous one copying over the elements. You might be better off with your own `for` loop.

Applying `Array.prototype.entries` to your function:

```js
const arr1 = [, , 3, 4]
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let result = true;
for (const [index, value] of arr1.entries()) {
    if (value !== arr2[index]) {
        result = false;
        break;
    }
}
console.log(result) // false
```

Answer (score 5):

Because the language design says so. ‍♂️

See [the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.every) which says:

> - Repeat, while k < len
>
>   - Let Pk be ToString(k).
>   - Let **kPresent be HasProperty**(O, Pk).
>   - ReturnIfAbrupt(kPresent).
>   - **If kPresent is true**, then

… then do the operation.

Since a value was never assigned to the `0` and `1` properties, the `HasProperty` test gives `false` so they are skipped over by the `If` rule.

Answer (score 3):

By docs of [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Description):

> callback is invoked only
>   for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked
>   for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned
>   values.

So, you are calling .every() with just truthy values of array1:

```js
const arr1 = [, , 3, 4]

arr1.every((x, idx) => {
 console.log(`element: ${x}`, `index: ${idx}`);
 return true;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The built in iteration functions (as described by others and defined in the specs) will skip values when HasProperty is false.

You could create your own shim for `all` which would check each value. This would be an expansion of the prototype. Alternatively, turning it into a function if this code were to be used in a wider scope would be a better design and require a slightly different call.

```js
const arr1 = [, , 3, 4];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

Array.prototype.all = function(callback){
 for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
     if(callback(this[i],i,this)) return false;
 }
 return true;
};

const result2 = arr1.all((item, index) => item === arr2[index]);
console.log(result2); // false
```